# Как ускорить выполнение rest запросов?

Tags: javascript

Имеется многоповторная отправка рест запроса, для отправки, допустим 4000 раз, требуется много времени,  каким способом можно ускорить данный процесс? Метод fetch использовать нет возможности

```
var ArrID = [];
var i = 0
func1();
function func1() {
  const createRequest = {
    url: "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search",
    method: 'GET'
  }

  pm.sendRequest(createRequest, function(err, res) {
    ArrID.push(res.json()[0].id);
    if (++i < 4000) {
      console.log(i);
      func1();
    } else {
        console.log("Ready!", "\n", 4000);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Ну так запускайте их параллельно. Но только 4000 запросов это по любому не быстро. Физику не обманешь.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как распараллелить, я пробовал через async/await, без использования fetch, не получилось, буду благодарен если напишите пример

Comment: последовательность ответов важна?

Comment: последовательность - нет